# Accessing contacts info without explicit permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-contacts

I am very new to app development. I am trying to read contact info without having to request permission to contacts (so I am using intents).

I get a URI with the following code in my main activity:

```
Intent selectContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
selectContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
if (selectContactIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(selectContactIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_CONTACT);
}
else {
    showContactRequiredMessage(view);
}
```

In another (sub)activity, I do the following:

```
contactUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.CONTACT_URI);

String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA2,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA3,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA4,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA5,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA6,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA7,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA8,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA9,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA10,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA11,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA12,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA13,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA14,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA15
};
Cursor contactResults = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

The last line throws the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column <any column after _ID>`

My app doesn't require all of the data in reality I just want to see what is available, I will most likely need first name, last name, phone, and email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Contacts without Permission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611833/read-contacts-without-permission)

Comment: The accepted answer in that question is actually what got me to the point I am now. If I try using the code snippet found there the result is the same, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is the MIME type that I set on the intent when I request the contact info. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Contacts) states `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE` should be used. However, if I use, something like `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE`, I can get display name and phone number. I am not sure if this means I will need to make multiple queries to get everything (the information shown in the contact picker changes when changing the type requested).

**TL;DR:** Used the "wrong" content type when creating the intent to select a contact.

Comment: i don't think you were wrong at first, the docs clearly state the two options: **(1)** using `Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE` to get temp. access to all fields of the contact or **(2)** access specific field using one of the `CommonDataKinds`...`CONTENT_TYPE`s. You are able to get **(2)** working, but **(1)** should be working as well, but maybe with different usage of the api

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment to your answer, you should be able to get the information expected without using a specific `CONTENT_TYPE` like `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE`.

The problem I see in your code is that you're trying to access `Data` table info from a `Contacts` table uri.

The `ContactsContract` api stored info on 3 main tables: Contacts, RawContacts and Data.
You were given a contactUri which points to an entry in the Contacts table, use the following code to read Data entries related to that contact:

```
long contactId = ContentUris.parseId(contactUri);
String projection = String[] { Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.DATA1 };
String selection = Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
  String mime = cursor.getString(0);
  String name = cursor.getString(1);
  String info = cursor.getString(2);
  if (mime.equals(CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
     Log.d(TAG, name + ": email = " + info;
  }
  if (mime.equals(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
     Log.d(TAG, name + ": phone = " + info;
  }
  // Add more mimetypes here if needed...
}
if (cursor != null) {
  cursor.close();
}
```